# Prove by induction T(n) = T(⌊n/2⌋) +T(⌊7n/16⌋) + n

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Prove by induction on n that T(n)=O(n), where T(0)=1,
T(n) = T(⌊n/2⌋) +T(⌊7n/16⌋) + n

So far I have,

Base Case: n = 1

[1/2] + [7/16] + 1

T(1) = 1

Induction hypothesis: Assume that for arbitrary n, T(n) ≤ n
Prove T(n+1) ≤ (n+1)?

Comment: If $T(0) = 1$, then $T(1) = 3$. Perhaps you want $T(0) = 0$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,
this is true if
$T(n)
=an + \sum_{j=1}^m T(\lfloor b_j n \rfloor)
$
where
$a, b_j > 0$
and
$\sum_{i=1}^m b_j 
< 1
$.
The proof is almost identical
to the following proof
for the coefficients 
in the original problem.

Suppose
$T(k)
\le ck
$
for $\lfloor 7n/16 \rfloor \le k < n$.

Then
$T(n)
=T(n/2)+T(7n/16)+n
\le c(n/2+7n/16)+n
= n(1+15c/16)
$
and this is
$\le cn$
if
$1+15c/16
\le c
$
or
$1\le c/16
$
or
$c \ge 16
$.

Note that this is where
$\sum b_j < 1$
would come in.

Therefore,
if we can find a $c \ge 16$
such that
$T(k) \le ck$
for
$\lfloor 7n/16 \rfloor \le k \le n-1$,
then
$T(n) \le cn$
for all larger $n$.

So choose a $c$ that works once
$n > 4$, say.